# monetdb bulk copy | bulk copy with python

Tags: python, csv, bigdata, monetdb, bulk-load

Am facing issue with file loading for bulk import in monetdb table. provided below are details for re creation of issue:

I have installed monetdb version 11.19.9 and python client for monetdb is 11.19.9 too.

Created dbform and it's working fine, I have connected to monetdb shell and through python api.

Now am trying to import dumped CSV file, content of the csv file are presented below:

```
44444444|ALI
55555555|JAFFRI
```

Table schema is defined as: * "Table already have 50 million rows, while csv have only two rows"

```
CREATE TABLE "voc"."test" (
    "id"   INTEGER,
    "data" VARCHAR(30)
);
```

- username and database name both are "voc"

command used to import file is as listed below.

```
root@monetdb:~# mclient -u voc -d voc -s  "COPY INTO test FROM STDIN" - < test.csv
password:
NULL byte in input
root@monetdb:~# mclient -u voc -d voc -s  "COPY INTO test FROM STDIN NULL AS ''" - < test.csv
password:
NULL byte in input
```

Error "NULL byte in input" is thrown and nothing is added to table.

For Python I have tried using following command:

```
import monetdb.sql
connection = monetdb.sql.connect(username="voc", password="voc", hostname="localhost", database="voc")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("COPY INTO test FROM 'test.csv'")
connection.commit()
```

This code throw Perm Exception:

```
COPY INTO: insufficient privileges: COPY INTO from file(s) requires database administrator rights, use 'COPY INTO "test" FROM STDIN' instead
```

Now I didn't found any example for python code to use with STDIN, Monetdb cursor does not offer copy_from unlike PostgreSQL where you can Pass file separately. Is there any solution for python?

OS?

```
uname -a
Linux monetdb 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

*** Python example worked fine with user monetdb but for terminal "NULL byte in input" is still exist.

Comment: Could you share the file you are trying to import?

Comment: I have shared content of the file in question. Do I need to share actual file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mclient -u voc -d voc -s  "COPY INTO test FROM STDIN" - < test.csv
```

works fine for me. The `NULL byte in input` error indicates that something is wrong with the file you are trying to load.

With regards to the other issue (calling COPY INTO from Python), the error message is quite clear as well. Try connecting as the `monetdb` user.

What also works is to inline the CSV data to be imported after the COPY INTO command. Example (Python):

```
cursor.execute("COPY 2 RECORDS INTO test FROM STDIN;\n44444444|AL\n55555555|JAFFRI")
```

The downside here is that you need to specify the number of records to be imported.

Comment: connecting with user monetdb worked fine, but how to use python for other users using STDIN?

Comment: Even if I can specify number of records, how it will be feasible to upload 100M rows file?

Comment: Load from file with user monetdb

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple table (create table dept (dept_id integer, dept_nm varchar(25)) and trying to insert records from file using Python and getting errors. All execute statements gives me same error message:

```
connection = monetdb.sql.connect(username="monetdb", password="monetdb", hostname="10.81.102.71", port=2234, database="demo")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("COPY INTO dept FROM 'C:\AWS\did.csv' USING DELIMITERS;")
cursor.execute("COPY INTO dept FROM 'C:\AWS\did.csv' USING DELIMITERS")
cursor.execute("COPY INTO dept FROM STDIN;\n44444444,'AL'\n55555555,'JAFFRI'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Q1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\monetdb\sql\cursors.py", line 175, in execute
    block = self.connection.execute(query)
  File "C:\Users\Q1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\monetdb\sql\connections.py", line 138, in execute
    return self.command('s' + query + ';')
  File "C:\Users\Q1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\monetdb\sql\connections.py", line 143, in command
    return self.mapi.cmd(command)
  File "C:\Users\Q1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\monetdb\mapi.py", line 202, in cmd
    raise OperationalError(response[1:])monetdb.exceptions.OperationalError: 25005!current transaction is aborted (please ROLLBACK)
```

Comment: comment First 2 inserts, use | pipe as separator instead of ","